# Python Logging Handler

Tags: python, logging

I want to add a userdefined variable to the logger format using ContextFiltering. My code is as follows :

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
CMDID='TEST'

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
  def filter(self,record):
    record.CMDID=CMDID
    return True

FORMAT='%(asctime)s [%(CMDID)s] - %(message)s'
logger=logging.getLogger("Test")
fh=logger.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("testing.log",maxBytes=1024,backupCount=5)
fh.setlevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())
logger.warning("WTH")
```

When I don't use a filehandler and just use a basicConfig for formatting then the code works fine. But on adding a Rotating File Handler I get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Line 16, in <module>
fh=logger.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("testing.log",maxBytes=1024,backupCount=5)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'RotatingFileHandler'
```

Now I have also tried using LoggerAdapters class for this, but it also throws weird errors which on further investigation I found out that there might be some issues with its documentation.

Can anyone help me regarding this issue and suggest me a way to effectively add contextual user defined info in my logger using this FileHandler.

P.S. I have tried the methods given in the python doc to no use

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change `logger.handlers.` to `logging.handlers.` and beware of typos (there is no `setlevel`-method, but a `setLevel`-method).

The following code works fine:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
CMDID='TEST'

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
  def filter(self,record):
    record.CMDID=CMDID
    return True

FORMAT='%(asctime)s [%(CMDID)s] - %(message)s'
logger=logging.getLogger("Test")
logger=logging.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("testing.log",maxBytes=1024,backupCount=5)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())
logger.warning("WTH")
```

Explanation: A logger-instance (`logger`) may have multiple handlers, accessible via it's `logger.handlers` atrribute. However, you want to instanciate a handler first (via `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler()` )  and use this handler (`fh`) with your logger (`logger.addHandler`). Doing this, your logger-instance now is aware of the handler:

```
In [4]: logger.handlers
Out[4]: [<logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler at 0x3e85b70>]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not completely relevant to the question, but wanted to add to this for total noobs like me because this is the top result when I searched for my problem.

Another reason you can get this issue is if you forget

```
import logging.handlers
```